# Is Firefox Automation on MacOS using NSAccessibility APIs / XCUITest Framework possible?

Tags: macos, firefox, accessibility, xcuitest

Can Firefox on MacOS be automated using NSAccessibility APIs or XCUITest framework?
I can access only few buttons of Firefox Window. I want to perform some actions on an alert box, which is from one of the Firefox extension javascript. I have checked using Accessibility inspector as well. However VoiceOver on MacOS can access all the buttons. So I think there is possibly some way to do it.

Any help how to get this working? TIA.[Please check Firefox window, which I am trying to automate, here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjq2c.png)